# How to associate a value to different given ranges of values

Tags: php, arrays

[edit : funny that "Hi/Hello/Greetings" at the start of a post is filtered out ;)]

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do the following :

I fetch from a database the TOP 5 errors that occured on an application. One of the fields is the number of times that error occured.

I display this TOP5 into a table on a webpage.

What I want to do is set a row background color depending on the number of occurences of the error :

0-5 : no color

6-10 : yellow

11-20 : orange

>=21 : red

What I've done for the moment is :

- set different threshold :

  ```
  $threshold1 = 6;
  $threshold2 = 11;
  $threshold3 = 21;
  ```
- set an array for each color :

  ```
  $warncolor = array(
      $threshold1 => '#ffe339',
      $threshold2 => '#FF9900',
      $threshold3 => '#ff2e2e'
  );
  ```
- then use ($row[3] being the value I fetch from the database) :

  ```
  if ($row[3] >= $threshold1 && $row[3] < $threshold2 ) {
      $color = $warncolor[$threshold1];
  } 
  elseif ($row[3] >= $threshold2 && $row[3] < $threshold3) {
      $color = $warncolor[$threshold2];
  }
  elseif ($row[3] >= $threshold3) {
      $color = $warncolor[$threshold3];
  }
  else {
      $color = '#FFFFFF';
  }
  ```
- I then use the $color variable in my table rows.

I have the feeling it could be greatly simplified ... I've search for a few hours on google/php manual ... and was unable to come up with a cleaner/nicer/optimal way to do it ...

So I've decided to come in here and ask for your help.

Thank you in advance.
Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a function like this to get the color:

```
function getColor ($count)
{
    $threshold1 = 6;
    $threshold2 = 11;
    $threshold3 = 21;

    $warncolor = array(
        $threshold3 => '#ff2e2e',
        $threshold2 => '#FF9900',
        $threshold1 => '#ffe339'            
    );

    foreach ($warncolor as $warn => $value) {
        if ($count >= $warn) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Comment: damn you. I just finish my answer very similar to yours and discovered, that you did it already. now i have to click on 'discard' :/

Comment: Thank you very much Marcosh. It worked like a charm and it's way better looking than what I did ;) By the way, you are missing one '{' on the "foreach" line.

Comment: @SébastienJoannin you're welcome. Thanks for the indication, I just edited the answer to correct it

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to marcosh's approach, but I'm forcing you to keep Thresholds and Colors in sync - if you need to maintain two separate places for these, chances are they may get out of sync in a few years and after 13 other maintenance-changes ;-)

```
function getColor ($count)
{
   $colors = array( 
      21 => "#ff2e2e",
      11 => "#ff9900",
       6 => "#ffe339"    
    ); // note how thresholds and colours directly relate!

    foreach ($colors as $threshold => $col)
    {
        if ($threshold < $count) return $col;
    }

    return "#ffffff";
}
```